# Floor number with schema.org microdata?

Tags: semantic-web, semantic-markup, street-address, microdata, postal-code

Any idea how to markup a floor number with [schema.org](http://schema.org/PostalAddress) microdata for a local business' postal address?

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <span itemprop="legalName">Company Limited</span>
    <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <div itemprop="streetAddress">Billy Street 100</div>
        <div>10th Floor</div>
        <div><span itemprop="addressLocality">Paris</span>, 
                <span itemprop="addressRegion">TX</span> 
                <span itemprop="postalCode">75462</span></div>
        <div itemprop="addressCountry">United States</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, is the above markup semantic?

If there's no floor number, should I use [RDFa](http://manu.sporny.org/2011/uber-comparison-rdfa-md-uf/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, schema.org doesn't have a property for secondary address line, which is where the floor number would go. postOfficeBoxNumber is as close as it gets, but it looks like it's reserved specifically for PO Box *numbers*, not the whole line that contains PO Box.

Perhaps you could put floor number in streetAddress, on a new line using a `<br>` tag.

Although I know a lot about street addresses (I work at SmartyStreets), I'm not a microdata expert: but from what I can tell, yes, the markup looks okay to me.

And you could use RDFa instead if you'd like: [Google supports it](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146898) for its rich snippets. Or you could have some fun and [extend schema.org](http://www.schema.org/docs/extension.html) for your needs.

Comment: Using RDFa sounds like a better idea, thank you! So when it comes to showing rich snippets in search results, does Google support RDFa 100% as much as it does it's preferred/endorsed microdata?

Comment: I assume so, based on Google's docs. Alternatively, since a floor number is *kind of like* a PO box (for your purposes), you might get away with putting it in the PO box slot anyway if you wanted to keep using schema.org microdata.

Comment: Use schema prefix from RDFa Initial Context http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1 and as @Matt said have fun extending schema. Google leads in supporting RDFa vocabs, microformats, while HTML5 microdata behavior will be guaranteed as given by http://www.w3.org/QA/2012/09/getting_html5_to_recommendatio.html